# Post Json data to Facebook time line using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: json, azure, http, azure-logic-apps

I have the following json data format it returned from a url,I need to post (title, url) on the Facebook timeline automatically by Azure logic Apps.

```
[{"ID":1,"title":"News title goes here","Details":"Some details about the news","link":"http://mywebsite.com","socialtype":"facebook"}]
```

how to use logic apps to do that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a  Recurrence(Timer) Action just for illustration purpose , Yours could be a Http Action with the json in the response. 
Next we need to add a parse json action to parse the response(json).
[image]

As it looks obvious the parse json action would be parsing the json structure you would have. To Generate the schema , paste the sample json in that section and click the link "use sample payload to generate schema".

After the Parse "Json Action" we need to append the "Post to TimeLine" Facebook Action to the workflow. This will ask for a facebook sign-in.

Select json output columns from the previous  action ("Parse Json") and 
map them to the appropriate fields, the title and link in the Facebook Post Timeline action. Everything should be set now to post to the Facebook timeline after parsing the json now. All set!.

[image]